# Copy one class properties to another class, with set the field to map in java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

copy one model class to another model class,
class A and class B different properties name,
want to set the class A properties to class B with manual mapping of field.

Comment: just like BeanUtils.copyProperties but field mapping is choice.

Comment: Have you checked `ModelMapper` and `DozerMapper`? Check this [DozerMapper Link](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/)

Comment: use apache's `BeanUtils.populate`

Comment: Please provide a code. You should have tried to write some code already

Answer (score 0):

ModelMapper provides multiple functionality, As per your requirement you can explore it out.
[Model Mapper Documentation Link](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/)

Giving a short example as below:

```
public class POJO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelMapper mapper  = new ModelMapper();
        TypeMap<Source, Destiation> typemap = mapper.createTypeMap(Source.class,Destiation.class);
        typemap.addMappings(mappings -> mappings.map(Source::getName,Destiation::setNom));
        typemap.addMappings(mappings -> mappings.map(Source::getLastName,Destiation::setPrenom));

        Source source = new Source();
        source.setName("John");
        source.setLastName("Doe");
        Destiation destiation = mapper.map(source,Destiation.class);
        System.out.println(destiation.toString());
    }
}
@Data //lombok annotation
class Source{
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

}
@Data //lombok annotation
class Destiation{
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
}
```