# Spring boot - How to Write Setter and Getter field Name Dynamic way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am getting the record last 6 months from the database. Based on the current Date. I am storing into an JSONArray when I am returning it - I am getting Serialization Error, because there is not Getter and setter. My data looks like this -

```
[
   {
       "userName": "Sita",
       "userEmail": "sita@gmail.com",
       "January": 3,
       "February": 10,
       "March": 1,
       "April": 3,
       "May": 32,
       "June": 31
   },
   {
       "userName": "Gita",
       "userEmail": "gita@gmail.com",
       "January": 3,
       "February": 10,
       "March": 1,
       "April": 3,
       "May": 32,
       "June": 31
   },
   {
       "userName": "Ram",
       "userEmail": "ram@gmail.com",
       "January": 3,
       "February": 10,
       "March": 1,
       "April": 3,
       "May": 32,
       "June": 31
   }
]
```

Now the question is --> Month Name can come dynamiclly. How I can I set this into my setter Getter Method, and call it from ServiceImp --> controller

I can't do like this -

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

private String userName;
   private String userName;
   private String January;
   private String February;
   private String March;
   private String April;
   private String May;
   private String June;
   private String July;
   private String August;
   private String September;
   private String October;
   private String November;
   private String December;
```

Its not the good way. I tried with many way. Can you please help me how I can achive this, and Write In a serviceImpl and Controller file. I am new to this spring boot, Any help would be appriciated.

If we keep like this, how do I map it to the specific month in a serviceImp ? Can please provide the code ? How do I map it. Like If I got the JSONObject like this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < filterUser.length(); i++) { 
    JSONObject jsb = (JSONObject) filterUser.get(i); 
    jsb.keySet().forEach(keyStr -> { 
         // Here Key is January, and jsb.get(keyStr) -> January data 
         // How can I set the setter and getter here ? 
    // }); 
    //  filteredTotalFeedbackData.put(i, jsb); 
}
```

Comment: as per your json structure why you think its not a good way. your json have 5-6 months already? Dynamic getter setter what exactly you are trying to achieve can you give one example

Comment: @Rishal - If we keep like this, how do I map it to the specific month in a serviceImp ? 

Can please provide the code ? How do I map it. Like If I got the JSONObject like this - 

 for(int i = 0; i < filterUser.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject jsb = (JSONObject) filterUser.get(i);
         
          jsb.keySet().forEach(keyStr ->
          {
           // Here Key is January, and jsb.get(keyStr) -> January data
                              //  How can I set the setter and getter here ?
          });
          filteredTotalFeedbackData.put(i, jsb);
      }

Comment: @Rishal - Month is Dynamic !!

Comment: Update the details in the question and also post minimal reproducible example which can detail out your question. follow the link [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does not help much. Can you please provide some code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things which I am assuming, because as per your details the question is somewhat unclear.

You have a database having records as per what you have mentioned in your question.

```
[
   {
       "userName": "Sita",
       "userEmail": "sita@gmail.com",
       "January": 3,
       "February": 10,
       "March": 1,
       "April": 3,
       "May": 32,
       "June": 31
   }
]
```

Its basically Json Object contained inside Json Array, So, as per Java you will have a Entity class to hold the values and that Entity class will be contained inside a List.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Details{
    private String userName;
    private String January;
    private String February;
    private String March;
    private String April;
    private String May;
    private String June;
    private String July;
    private String August;
    private String September;
    private String October;
    private String November;
    private String December;
}
```

Your result after fetching the data from database will be something like,

```
List<Details> result = //database call (Repository call);
```

Now, this all things will be happening inside some service class , we are calling that service class as `DetailsServiceImpl.java`

**Repository**

```
@Repository
interface DetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<Details,Long>{
    
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class DetailsServiceImpl{
    private final DetailsRepository detailsRepository;
    
    public List<DetailsDto> getLastSixMonthsData(){
        //List<Details> result = //detailsRepository database call;

        //either use Modelmapper to copy the data from entity to DTO
        //BeanUtils can also be used.
        return //Copied ArrayList<DetailsDto>(); which will be populated by ModelMapper or BeanUtils.
    }
}
```

**DTO**
This `DTO` is responsible for rendering the data to `controller`, or you can say sending the `representable` data to `controller`.

```
@Data
//@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) can be used if you dont want non-null values in your response.
class DetailsDto{
    private String userName;
    private String January;
    private String February;
    private String March;
    private String April;
    private String May;
    private String June;
    private String July;
    private String August;
    private String September;
    private String October;
    private String November;
    private String December;
}
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class DetailsController{
    private final DetailsServiceImpl detailsService;
    public ResponseEntity<List<DetailsDto>> getDetailsLastSixMonths(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<DetailsDto>>(detailsService.getLastSixMonthsData(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Links to follow
[How to use BeanUtils.copyProperties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763278/how-to-use-beanutils-copyproperties)

[Copy one class properties to another class, with set the field to map in java Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72951449/copy-one-class-properties-to-another-class-with-set-the-field-to-map-in-java-sp/72953276#72953276)

No need to use `JSONObject` and operating on each `object`. Hope it helps.